# Count maxdate with condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, maxdate

(apologies if I don't format question correctly, this is my first post).

I have following example data:

```
a.label |   b.recipient_id| b.action|b.creation_date  
Books | Recipient1 |    0 | 01/04/2018  
Books | Recipient1 |    1 | 02/04/2018  
Books | Recipient1 |    0 | 03/04/2018  
Books | Recipient1 |    1 | 04/04/2018  
Books | Recipient2 |    1 | 05/04/2018  
Books | Recipient2 |    0 | 06/04/2018  
Books | Recipient2 |    0 | 07/04/2018  
Books | Recipient2 |    1 | 08/04/2018  
Books | Recipient3 |    1 | 13/04/2018  
Books | Recipient3 |    0 | 14/04/2018  
Books | Recipient3 |    1 | 15/04/2018  
Books | Recipient3 |    0 | 16/04/2018
```

I would like to count recipient_ids for which max(creation_date) action = 1

If for max(creation_date) action is equal to 0 I do not want to count this recipient at all.

So in my example data above I would like to count Recipient1 and Recipient2 but not Recipient3.

I tried variations of following but nothing worked so far

```
SELECT count(b.recipient_id)
FROM Services a, Subscriptions b,
(SELECT recipient_id,MAX(creation_date)
FROM Subscriptions
GROUP BY recipient_id) c
WHERE a.SERVICE_ID = b.SERVICE_ID
AND b.recipient_id = c.recipient_id
AND b."ACTION" = '1'
AND a.LABEL = 'Books'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method, using two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select su.recipient_id
      from services se join
           subscriptions su
           on se.service_id = su.service_id
      where se.label = 'BOOKS'
      group by su.recipient_id
      having max(su.creation_date) = max(case when su.action = 1 then su.creation_date)
     ) ss;
```

The `having` clause checks that the final status is `1`.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases, such as abbreviations of the table name, rather than arbitrary letters.
- Use single quotes to delimit strings.  Double quotes can be used to escape identifiers, if that is necessary.